# Accessing Acumatica through VB.Net ... getting started

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, acumatica

Is anyone using VB.Net to access the Acumatica contract based REST API?  I really need some help getting started.  I am experienced in VB.Net, but new to Acumatica and I am a little overwhelmed by all of the documentation.  I just want to start with something simple ... for example, log into Acumatica, get a list of stock parts & log out.  Does anyone have any VB.Net code they would be willing to share?  Or maybe a tutorial you could point me to?  I spent a few hours looking through a lot of documentation but could not seem to find what I was looking for to get me started.  I would appreciate any help you can provide.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yeah there sure is a heap of documentation. But most of the examples I've seen are C#,  even so all the process is pretty much 1:1 and are relative simple to convert to vb.net.  Perhaps you might be best to actually make a start yourself and come back with specific issues.  This site isn't really a code writing or recommendation tutorials.  More geared to problem solving

Comment: I wouldn't deign to call that a REST API. It's a SOAP-like web service with JSON serialization, but it doesn't apply RESTful concepts. Having to log in *and log out*, using cookies, using `PUT` for what should be a `POST` (based on usage, such as not returning 201 Created and not `PUT`ting to the resource URI where you could subsequently `GET` the created record). I can't tell if that's contributing to your difficulties, but it certainly won't help if you're expecting it to be a "REST API" as it claims to be.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PHP binding for the Acumatica REST APIs. Some of the criticisms above are somewhat valid...it's a little unique as APIs go, and not very well documented. That's why to get started... you will want to get Postman: https://www.postman.com/

In Postman, setup a POST request to http://youracumsticaurl/entity/auth/login
Use JSON body with your user/pass/company details:
{
"name" : "admin",
"password" : "yourpass",
"company" : "Company name full text",
"locale" : "en-US"
}
for company....use the full text of the company in the tenant...not the id.

Next with Postman do a simple get request for an item:
http://localhost/Acumatica2021R2/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem/someitemid

...where "someitemid" is a valid stock item id

Once you get that far, you can start using Postman to write your VB.NET API calls. Here is some info on calling a REST web service with VB.NET: https://dotnetco.de/setup-post-rest-webservice-asp-net-vb-net/

It takes some messing around but the REST API works pretty well once you get your calls setup correctly. I login and logout on every call, which is probably not best practice but avoids some of the session management headaches with cookies and Acumatica. YMMV with that depending on use case and call volume.

Answer (score 0):

I use the rest api client available on the Acumatica github site.  (link below)

I'm using C# in my project, but there's no reason you couldn't use this library with vb.net.

I had to update the library to add custom fields and custom endpoints which would require you update the code in C#, but if you just want the base endpoints it should work fine.

https://github.com/Acumatica/AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have a probably silly question ... do I need to download the project & build it myself?

Comment: Yes, you have to build it your self.  I don't believe any binary files are available.